# Why got "Column 'ASD' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification"?

Tags: java, sql, jsp, netbeans-8

While run my code I got the following exception:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Column 'ASD' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE statement then 'ASD' is not a column in the target table. This is the error that print for exception e

Here is my code:

```java
String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"; 
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/"; 
String database = "EmployeeDB"; 
String DBid = "app"; 
String DBpass = "app";
    <%
    try{
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl+database, DBid, DBpass);
    Statement stt=connection.createStatement();
    //String sql ="select * from USERPROFILE where username="+Sname;
    String sql ="select * from USERPROFILE where username="+Sname;
    

    out.print("<br>4Welcome to Session Page: SQL "+sql);
    out.print("<br>5Welcome to Session Page: result "+Spass);
    ResultSet resultSQL = stt.executeQuery(sql);
    out.print("<br>6Welcome to Session Page: result "+Spass);
    while(resultSQL.next()){
    out.print("<br>7Welcome to Session Page: Name "+Sname+ " Pass "+Spass);
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="history.back()">Go Back</button>
<h1>Update data from database in jsp</h1>
<form method="post" action="update-process.jsp">
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%=resultSQL.getString("id") %>">
Username:<br>
<input type="text" name="username" value="<%=resultSQL.getString("username") %>">
<br>
Password:<br>
<input type="text" name="password" value="<%=resultSQL.getString("password") %>">
<br>
Contact:<br>
<input type="text" name="contact" value="<%=resultSQL.getString("contact") %>">
<br>
Email:<br>
<input type="text" name="password" value="<%=resultSQL.getString("email") %>">
<br>
Work hour per Week<br>
<input type="text" name="workhour" value="<%=resultSQL.getString("workhour") %>">
<br>
Reward:<br>
<input type="text" name="reward" value="<%=resultSQL.getString("reward") %>">
<br>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to update?');">
</form>
<%
    }
    connection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: One: You shouldn't use scriptlets. Two: You should read up on sql injection. Three: `String sql ="select * from USERPROFILE where username='"+Sname+"'";` Four: Use a `PreparedStatement` instead. Five: Never post a question like this without including the `Exception` - which you seem to be printing.

Comment: Java Code/SQL does not belong in JSP.

Comment: OP, where do you think `e.printStackTrace();` is printing out?

Comment: I’d guess that your code is throwing an exception, which you are ignoring. Remove your catch block.

Comment: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Column 'ASD' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE statement then 'ASD' is not a column in the target table.    This is the error that print for exception e

Comment: String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver";
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/";
String database = "EmployeeDB";
String DBid = "app";
String DBpass = "app";                                                                                                         This for the connectionUrl and database

Comment: @MuhammadShafiqzy Edit your question to add exception and connection details in it. Their place is there, not in comments.

Comment: Thank you, Sir, everything is good now after I do what you said.

Comment: @MuhammadShafiqzy Glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `Sname` is String, then query should be `SELECT * FROM USERPROFILE WHERE username='"+ Sname +"'"`. for **Integer** use quotes like `"+ Integer +"` and for **String** use quotes like `'"+ String +"'`

**Here down is some mistake in your code.**

- This query is not secure, you have to use **[`Parameterized Queries`](https://www.baeldung.com/sql-injection)** for secure your data.
- To avoid any Syntax error, you have to use `PreparedStatement` instead `Statement`.
- Put all code inside `<form>` tag because if code is outside to the `<form>` tag then you are not allowed for submit in form.

**Here down is modified code with **`Parameterized Queries`**.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   <button onclick="history.back()">Go Back</button>
   <h1>Update data from database in jsp</h1>
   <form method="post" action="update-process.jsp">
   <%
       try{
           String sql ="SELECT * FROM USERPROFILE WHERE username = ?";
           Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl + database, DBid, DBpass);
           PreparedStatement stt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
           stt.setString(1, Sname);

           out.print("<br>4Welcome to Session Page: SQL " + sql);
           out.print("<br>5Welcome to Session Page: result " + Spass);

           ResultSet resultSQL = pst.executeQuery();

           out.print("<br>6Welcome to Session Page: result " + Spass);

           while(resultSQL.next()){
                out.print("<br>7Welcome to Session Page: Name " + Sname + " Pass " + Spass);
   %>
   <br>
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%=resultSQL.getString("id") %>">
   Username:<br>
   <input type="text" name="username" value="<%=resultSQL.getString("username") %>">
   <br>
   Password:<br>
   <input type="text" name="password" value="<%=resultSQL.getString("password") %>">
   <br>
   Contact:<br>
   <input type="text" name="contact" value="<%=resultSQL.getString("contact") %>">
   <br>
   Email:<br>
   <input type="text" name="password" value="<%=resultSQL.getString("email") %>">
   <br>
   Work hour per Week<br>
   <input type="text" name="workhour" value="<%=resultSQL.getString("workhour") %>">
   <br>
   Reward:<br>
   <input type="text" name="reward" value="<%=resultSQL.getString("reward") %>">
   <br>
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to update?');">
<%
           }
           sst.close();
           connection.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
%>
</form>
```